# Crystal Reports Cross tab group

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab, crystal-reports-2008, summary

Is there a way to set a cross tab summary to evaluate on change of group like a running total would? I need to set up a cross tab to appear in the report footer that evaluates the group, not the details.

I have a date difference in the group header, and then details below. I'd like the cross tab to show the average date diff, max, and min date difference. How ever when I do a normal cross tab it is evaluating the date difference for every line of details and not for each group.

Comment: Have you tried putting the crosstab in a subreport, and putting that subreport in the group footer?

Comment: Wouldn't that evaluate for each instance of the group still since it's in the group footer? I'm trying to have it show the summaries for the whole report but the info I need to summarize lies in the group header

Comment: The purpose of cross-tab is to show you certain aggregated function results (min, max etc) for a combination two other values. If the group values that contain the date difference is the first one, what is the other value you wish to combine with within the cross-tab? Are you sure this is the correct object to use?

Comment: What I ended up doing is making a few running total fields that evaluate on change of group then I was able to use those running total fields in the cross tab.